# Website not properly indexed by Google search console says "'noindex' detected in 'robots' meta tag" while this is not the case

Tags: seo, google-search-console, robots.txt, meta-robots

### TLTR

**I have a website (SPA) where SEO is very important. It was very poorly indexed and search console tells me it is due to 'noindex' in the robots meta, while I cannot see how Google comes to that conclusion.**

## BACKGROUND

I have this Single Page Application built with VueJS, which I launched at the start of this year. I noticed it was poorly indexed in Google. Google has missed out on indexing indexed a lot of my pages; including the most important ones with the most content. I do control the robots meta tag trough javascript, but cannot see how this would cause these issues.

## CASE

I will post an example URL here where indexing by Google is blocked, while I want it to be indexed and give all information/research I have found about it:

#### URLS:

https://trainervinden.nl/blog/afvallen-met-een-personal-trainer

Alternative URL, different page type, same results:
https://trainervinden.nl/trainer/marit-de-heer

#### Sitemap

The page is part of the sitemap:
https://trainervinden.nl/sitemap.xml

#### Robots.txt

We don't have one AFAIK.

#### Chrome Inspector

I see the robots meta tag in header from Chrome inspector, and it looks good to me:

[image: Meta tag in header from inspector]

#### Page Source

Default robots meta tag from page source (it is a SPA though, and robots meta tag is also controlled by javascript):
[image: Robots meta in Page source from SPA]

#### Web Developer Tools Chrome Plugin

Response headers, looking good to me. No robots stuff here:

[image: Result response headers Web Developer Tools]

Meta tags from Web Developer Tools, still looking as I expect:

[image: Meta tags from Web Developer Tools]

#### Google Search Console

Pushing the button `Test live url` (the same results as the existing info behind tab Google Index) gives results I do not understand:

[image: Result for Test live url]

**I can provide any extra information needed to solve this issue; just ask!**

So basically I have no idea where this "no-index" Google sees is coming from and am a web guy in despair right now. Any hint helping me out is much appreciated; more than you can imagine at this point :)

Comment: Why do you describe that as a single page site?  It clearly has lots of pages.

Comment: Hi Stephen, a SPA (Single Page Application) is just a website that uses javascript to render the website in the client (browser of the user). It is a technique rather than a limit on number of pages and my website is a SPA.

Comment: I would use the terminology "JavaScript rendered" rather than "single page application" in such a case.

Comment: Sure, although it is a really widely used term for these modern kind of applications.

Answer (score 2):

"index" is not an approved value for use in a robots meta tag.  See: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag  Instead you should use "all".

```
<meta name=robots content=all>
```

Alternatively, you can omit the meta robots tag altogether.  Without a tag, the default is to allow crawling and indexing.

I think is what is happening is that Google is seeing "index" and matching it to the closest possible approved value, which is "noindex."

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer. I have changed the content to `all` as you suggested. I cannot believe I missed that. My issue is still not fixed though. The problem persists. I have found out a way of reproducing the issue though. If I check the pages through https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly I see page is not found (while it is found through normal browser). The fact that it is not found redirects the user to a "not found" page which sets the robots meta tag to `noindex`.

Comment: I'm not sure how the mobile friendly test gets to the 404 page.   I get a page on the command line with `curl --head https://trainervinden.nl/blog/afvallen-met-een-personal-trainer` which results in a "200 OK" status.   Testing in a variety of browsers shows problems with Internet Explorer not showing the page, but IE doesn't show a 404 error either:  https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i2a11f6a3a18c91f/screenshots/zeec05c7401485a089b9

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is going wrong right now. Will let you know if I find out what is going on. It is actually not a `404` status even if the element is not found. It seems to be due to CORS issues with the backend.

Comment: The issues have been fixed and were cause by a robots.txt file on the api endpoints... The `noindex` was due to a redirect to a not found if an error occurred when the data was fetched I built into the frontend